# Double pointers in a linked list

Tags: c

I'm trying to store a string in a linked list, but for some reason, I keep getting segmentaion fault error.
I've tried everything, and I feel I'm missing something really stupid and easy, please any thoughts?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 60
typedef struct Node
{
    char *getInput;
    struct Node *next;

} Node;
typedef struct list
{
    Node *head;
} list;

void readText(Node **a)
{
    
  char c;
    int i = 0;
     while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        (*a)->getInput[i++] = c;
}
void main()
{
    Node *b;
  
    b->getInput = (char *)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(char));
    if (b == NULL)
    {
        printf("sadsa");
        exit(1);
    }
   readText(&b);
    printf("%s", b->getInput);
}
```

Comment: On the second line of main, you assign to `b->getInput` but `b` is uninitialized.

Comment: `clang -Wall prog.c` or `gcc -Wall prog.c` will warn about this.

Answer (score 0):

- You mave to allocate a valid region and assign to `b` before dereferencing that.
- Also checking if `b` is not `NULL` must be taken place before dereferencing.
- You should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.
- `getchar()` returns `int`, so the return value should be assigned to an `int` variable. Otherwise, it will be difficult to distinguish between a valid character and EOF.
- You should terminate strings by adding terminating null-character before using that for `%s`. (In this case it is not necessary because the buffer is initialized to zero via `calloc()`, but this will improve safety for another usage of the function)

```
void readText(Node **a)
{
    
    int c; /* use proper type */
    int i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        (*a)->getInput[i++] = c;
    (*a)->getInput[i] = '\0'; /* terminate the string */
}

int main(void) /* use standard signature */
{
    Node *b = malloc(sizeof(*b)); /* allocate buffer */
    if (b == NULL) /* check if allocation is successful before dereferencing */
    {
        printf("sadsa");
        exit(1);
    }
    b->getInput = (char *)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(char));
    readText(&b);
    printf("%s", b->getInput);
}
```

Comment: The terminating `\0` is good practice, but in this case unnecessary because the memory is zero-initialized with calloc.

Comment: @PaulHankin Oops, I saw that at the beginning but forgot later.